# Not able to see plus sign even if I pass true from hasChildren function in Qt

Tags: qt, qtreeview, qabstractitemmodel

I am implementing tree view, I have sub classed my model and view. initially I am populating all the top level items and I don't know how many child's are there for each top level items but I know all the top level items has a child's, so I have re-implemented hasChildren() function and pass true for all the top level items, but I am not able to see + sign for the top level items even i pass true. Please let me know the problem

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure that the `QAbstractItemModel::rowCount()` implementation returns non zero value for that nodes too.

Comment: Then what is the use of hasChildren() function, As per my knowledge when we show the data initially instead of querying rowCount() and get to know there is children, hasChildren() function will be called and then get to know weather this item has child's or not. according to that it will create the + sign. when we expand it it childCount() should be called.  Please correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: Implementing `rowCount` is enough. `hasChildren` uses `rowCount` and `columnCount` by default. You should only reimplement `hasChildren` if there is more efficient way to implement it.