# why to use hasChildren function in qAbstractitemModel

Tags: qt, qabstractitemmodel

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29817018/not-able-to-see-plus-sign-even-if-i-pass-true-from-haschildren-function-in-qt?noredirect=1#comment47761089_29817018/%22here%22) I got the doubt that.

Then what is the use of hasChildren() function, As per my knowledge when we show the data initially instead of querying rowCount() and get to know there is children, hasChildren() function will be called and then get to know weather this item has child's or not. according to that it will create the + sign. when we expand it it childCount() should be called. Please correct me If I am wrong